# How to get link of wms layer in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wms

How to Get WMS links of all published layers from specific workspace and store in Geoserver using gsconfig  or any environment.
I want to get all WMS links of all layers in excel? I can get a published layer name from below code.

```
from geoserver.catalog import Catalog  
cat=Catalog("http:// localhost:8080/geoserver/rest")  
myResource = cat.get_resources(store='storeName', workspace='workspaceName')  
layers = cat.get_layers(myResource)  
for rss in myResorce:  
  print rss.name
```

Comment: Hi @swamy and welcome to GIS Stack Exchange. When posting a code sample it helps to use the code tags using the { } button